# BlueSnap virtual terminal - setting up a shortlist of products

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, bluesnap

I've been using the BlueSnap virtual terminal for a few months now, to sell subscriptions with specific parameters, offer discounts etc.

When I started off I only had a few subscriptions and selecting the right one from the drop-down list was easy - but now every time I go to select I have to scroll through a long list of subscriptions, most of which are not relevant anymore for new sales.

Is there anything I can do to "trim down" this list to a smaller, manageable set? Changing the list is something that I may need to change day-to-day, so I need something flexible.

I don't want to delete the old subscriptions or deactivate them because I still get revenue from them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The virtual terminal in BlueSnap can be configured quite extensively - you can add and remove fields, and you can add and remove specific SKUs from the product list - or even remove the product selection entirely.

To do it, you need to login to your control panel, and in the right top side click on "Settings", and under it click on "Virtual Terminal Settings".

[image: settings menu]

In the screen that opens up scroll to the bottom of the screen where you will find a list of products. If nothing is selected - or if the "Display all contracts" top option is selected, it means you will see all active SKUs in your virtual terminal.

To make a shortlist, simply multiple-select the SKUs you wish from the list (using Ctrl or Shift) and click "Submit" from the top right corner.

[image: multiple-selection]

Now when you'll go back to the Virtual Terminal, you will only have the SKUs you selected presented for selection. You can change this selection at any time without changing the setup of your subscriptions in any way.

[image: virtual terminal shortlist]

I hope it helped!